# Pandas: Check if row has similar values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm generating an overlay for a map using pandas and used:

```
if ((df['latitude'] == new_latitude) & (df['longitude'] == new_longitude)).any():
   continue
```

to make sure that I don't produce duplicate points. But I am starting to produce points that are 0.001 different (in either longitude, latitude or both) than one already produced. How can I prevent this in a similar manner as above?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can subtract from the entire series and then just filter the points:

```
thresh = 0.001
lat = df.loc[(df['latitude'] - new_latitude).abs() > thresh, 'latitude']
lon = df.loc[(df['longtitude'] - new_longtitude).abs() > thresh, 'longtitude']
```

this uses `abs` to get the absolute value to generate a boolean mask and filter all the duplicate and near duplicate values out.

Comment: Is this to be used once the pandas dataframe is complete? I'm looking to stop producing them with an if statement ideally as once one is produced it causes more points with a 0.001 difference to be produced so increases the time to run massively.

Comment: You'll have to explain how the data is loaded, generally though growing a df iteratively is expensive

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`numpy.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) function with `atol` setted to your precision:

```
import numpy as np
prec = 0.001
np.isclose(df['latitude'], new_latitude, atol=prec)

if ((np.isclose(df['latitude'], new_latitude, prec) & (np.isclose(df['longitude'], new_longitude, prec)).any():
   continue
```